# connecting three select boxes with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sql

I want to have select boxes that are linked to each other. they need to work from up to down. and on the end in a other box it must not be a select box but a input that is read only but is linked to the last select bar. only the first and the second select box is connected but the second and third must be connected to with the outcome of the first one. all is connected with a database.

```
<select name="funcgroep" class="input" id="functiegroep" onchange="giveSelection(this.value)">
<option></option>
<option value="01">01</option></select>

<p>Functieschaal</p> 
<select name="funcschaal" class="input" id="functieschaal">
<option value="01A" data-option="01">01A</option><option value="01B" data-option="01">01B</option><option value="01C" data-option="01">01C</option></select>

<p>Periodiek </p>
<select name="periodiek" class="input" id="periodiek">
<option></option>
<option data-option="01A">A</option><option data-option="01A">P01</option><option data-option="01A">P02</option><option data-option="01A">P03</option><option data-option="01A">P04</option></select><br>
```

javascript

```
<script>
var functiegroep = document.querySelector('#functiegroep');
var functieschaal = document.querySelector('#functieschaal');
var options2 = functieschaal.querySelectorAll('option');

function giveSelection(functiegroepValue) {
  functieschaal.innerHTML = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < options2.length; i++) {
    if(options2[i].dataset.option === functiegroepValue) {
      functieschaal.appendChild(options2[i]);
    }
  }
}

giveSelection(functiegroep.value);
</script>
```

Comment: "Connected" how? What data would be displayed in each select box? And what data do you expect to be displayed in each select box when making a selection? It's super un-clear what you actually want.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "all is connected with a database"? What database? Connected how?

Comment: the <option> is generated with php that comes in the select boxes. and that must me the way the select boxes must linked to each other with javascript. the second select must listen to the first select box and the third must listen to the second select box with outcome from the first. and their must be a and on the end their must be a read only box where there is a result from all the select boxes.

Comment: I want to help you, I really do, but that is the worst explanation I have ever seen. You say: "the second select must listen to the first select box and the third must listen to the second select box with outcome from the first" That's like a riddle. Seriously, give us some example data of what you want to happen (like, if 'Australia' is selected in the first box, 'United Kingdom' should show in the second box and 'United States' in the third).

Comment: Also, I don't know if English is your native language or not, but you really need to at least check what you've written before posting. For example: "and their must be a and on the end" First, it's spelled "there" ("their" is possessive), and second, there appears to be one or more missing words in that sentence, which makes it unintelligible. Or, if you meant there should be an `and` on the end, you should put the `and` in a code block like I've done so that we can tell it's not just another word in the sentence.